# How to fix Task dependency sequence in OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, dependencies, openmp

I am writing a code for testing workflow sequence of task dependency using OpenMP.

I have 4 tasks types.

- **`Task 1`** has 1 task,
- **`Task 2`** and **`Task 3`** have 5 tasks respectively (i=0,2,4,6,8) and
- **`Task 4`** has 1 task.

They are working parallel, but the problem is that the sequence is not what I expect.

What I want is that:

**`Task 1:`** should have task dependency on first task of  **`Task 2`**.

**`Task 2:`** all 5 tasks should have dependency on **`Task 3`** all 5 tasks respectively.

**`Task 3:`** 3rd and 4th tasks should have dependency on **`Task 4`**.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
int x,y;
int i,j;
int a[10];
for(x=0; x<10; x++){
  a[x] = x+1;
}
omp_set_num_threads(10);
printf("number of thread = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp master
  {
#pragma omp task depend (out:a[0:2])
     {
        sleep(2);
        a[0] = 1; // work only parameter is a[0]
        printf("1\n");
     }
  }
#pragma omp for
     for(i=0; i<10; i+=2){
        #pragma omp task depend(in:a[i:2]) depend(out:a[i:2])
       {
          sleep(2);
          a[i] = a[0];
          a[i+1] = a[1];
          printf("2 :: i = %d\n", i);
       }
     }
#pragma omp for
     for(j=0; j<10; j+=2){
    #pragma omp task depend(in:a[j:2]) depend(out:a[j:2])
        {
           sleep(2);
           a[j] = a[j]*2;
           a[j+1] = a[j+1]*2;
           printf("3 :: j = %d\n", j);
        }
     }
 #pragma omp master
 #pragma omp task depend (in:a[6:4])
     {
        sleep(2);
        for(x=0; x<10; x++){
           printf("%d, ", a[x]);
        }
        printf("end\n");

     }

 }
  return 0;
}
```

In short, they look like this :
Task list :

- Task 1 : set a[0]
- Task 2-0, 2-2, 2-4, 2-6, 2-8 : copy a[0], a[1] to a[i], a[i+1]
- Task 3-0, 3-2, 3-4, 3-6, 3-8 : make a[i], a[i+1] to double value
- Task 4 : print a[0:10]

Dependencies :

Task 1 -> Task 2-0 -> Task 3-0

Task 2-2 -> Task 3-2

Task 2-4 -> Task 3-4

Task 2-6 -> Task 3-6 -> Task 4

Task 2-8 -> Task 3-8 -> Task 4

**So, what I expect the flow to be like this :**

```
Step 1 : Task 1 / Task 2-2 / Task 2-4 / Task 2-6 / Task 2-8

(sleep)     ↓        ↓            ↓          ↓        ↓

Step 2 : Task2-0 / Task 3-2 / Task 3-4 / Task 3-6 / Task 3-8

(sleep)     ↓                                ↓        ↓

Step 3 : Task3-0                               Task 4
```

**Output : 1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4 end**

**But, right now I am getting this output :**

```
Step 1 : Task 1 / Task 2-2 / Task 2-4 / Task 2-6 / Task 2-8

(sleep)      ↓       ↓           ↓           ↓         ↓


Step 2 : Task2-0     ↓           ↓           ↓         ↓


(sleep)      ↓       ↓           ↓           ↓         ↓

Step 3 : Task3-0 / Task 3-2 / Task 3-4 / Task 3-6 / Task 3-8

(sleep)                                      ↓         ↓

Step 4 :                                        Task4
```

**Output : 2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4, end**

**1) How can I make correct dependency sequence?**

**2) By doing some search on internet, I guess depend clause in inner array should be like this `array[start:size]`, but I am not sure how can I write in my code?**

I am not familiar with OpenMP depend clause. Please advise me on this question.

Comment: What is the actual real-world context of your question? Are you ready to use tools that are adequately equipped for a principal solving the postulated goal, or are you focused on how to move an already pre-selected technology as close as possible to the goal, that your try to solve? Thanks for this disambiguation.

Comment: @user3666197 My focus is on "are you focused on how to move an already pre-selected technology as close as possible to the goal, that your try to solve?"      My main goal is to understand the sequential working when using OpenMp dependency clause. For example, ( depend(out:a[i:2]).